# How to kill an insect without touching it?

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics, everyday-life, laser-interaction

Apart from the interception by a sufficiently powerful laser, what would be the means to neutralize (kill/repel) an insect in full flight and indoors (so no water, pepper, etc), and without touching it by physical contact.

Would ultra-targeted ultrasound be possible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this post fits Physics SE

Comment: The question is a bit too open-ended. For example, sending a small black hole past to destroy it with tidal forces and radiation from an accretion disk is a possible answer...

Answer (score 2):

There are electronic insect control products (a.k.a "bug zappers"). They involve a high voltage (but low, non-lethal, current) transformer output. Generally they are used outdoors, but I've read some say they can be used indoors as well. As always, however, use in accordance with the manufacturer's instructions.

The output voltage of a step up transformer with associated output circuitry generally supplies at least 2,000 V. The voltage is applied across two wire-mesh grids located within a metal housing. The grids are separated by a tiny gap, about the size of a typical insect. A UV light lures the insects to the device. When they get into the gap an electrical discharge goes through their bodies.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've removed a comment discussion.

Comment: @rob What a shame.  It could have saved some insects' lives.